# wix custom action missing dll MSVCR100D.dll

Tags: visual-c++, wix, windows-installer

I am writing an installer using wix. I have also written custom actions. But while installing the MSI the installation fails because the target system does not have `MSVCR100D.dll`

I am linking using `/MTd` option which is what the docs I read suggested for static linking.

Can anyone please let me know how to link `msvcr100d.dll` statically so that even if `msvcr100d.dll` is not present on the target system, my MSI installation succeeds?

Answer (score 5):

The "D" in MSVCR100D.dll indicates that your native custom action DLL is a debug DLL.  The "D" dependency won't be on the target machine unless they have various SDKs installed.  Rebuild your DLL in release and the dependency will change to MSVCR100.dll

Also, since you are using WiX / Votive, there is a Visual Studio WiX C++ CA project type that creates the project for you.  My experience has been that all of the default compiler and linker settings are good to go out of the box when you use that project type.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same problem.  In my case, I am trying to debug my custom actions running in the context of the installer, so I do want to install debug versions.

The Visual Studio debug CRT DLL's are not redistributable, by Microsoft policy.  Apparently, it seems furthermore that a 64-bit DLL compiled with Visual Studio 2010 using /MTd (static linking, debug configuration) produces output with a dependency on MSVCR100D.dll.  In the 64-bit release configuration, as expected, compiling with /MT results in no dependency on MSVCR100.dll.

One solution is to install Visual Studio on the target test machine.  Microsoft offers further suggestions [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx)